# Linking issues with libMathEval

Tags: c++, c, linker, libraries

I have one big source code which I want to divide into some modules (.h and .c files)...Because I have a unique source code file of 2000 lines...

Lets get into the problem:

-I am using a expression library libMathEval in that code...

-I compile the big source code file with the following command:

```
gcc -DMAX_ESTRELLAS_SELECCIONADAS=1000000 crowd_2cond.c -lmatheval -o run2sec
```

-To run I use:

```
./run2sec ./fparameters.txt
```

-The results in the konsole are:

```
Tiempo para lectura de ficheros, calculo de expresiones, creacion de estructuras (listas, IndiceAVL y IndiceVector) y liberacion de IndiceAVL: 3.7689 segundos
Tiempo para algoritmo: **68.7716 segundos**
Tiempo para escritura de ficheros y liberacion de memoria: 3.9501 segundos
Tiempo SECUENCIAL total (avl-serializado 2-index 2-cond Optimizado): 76.4906 segundos
```

The program produce a file output that is correct...

But I want to separate that big source file in different modules...so I started with one function of the big file, so now I have two files (three with the header):

crowd_2cond.c (contains the main and all the functions minus the one that is moved to the next file entrada.c)

entrada.c (header entrada.h): contains only one big function...

So to generate the executable I use the following commands:

```
gcc -c entrada.c
gcc -c -DMAX_ESTRELLAS_SELECCIONADAS=1000000 crowd_2cond.c
gcc -o run2sec crowd_2cond.o -lmatheval entrada.o
```

Again to run I used:

```
./run2sec ./fparameters.txt
```

The results showed are:

```
Tiempo para lectura de ficheros, calculo de expresiones, creacion de estructuras (listas, IndiceAVL y IndiceVector) y liberacion de IndiceAVL: 3.7941 segundos
Tiempo para algoritmo: **1.4577 segundos**
Tiempo para escritura de ficheros y liberacion de memoria: 3.6116 segundos
Tiempo SECUENCIAL total (avl-serializado 2-index 2-cond Optimizado): 8.8634 segundos
```

The program produce a file output that in this case is not correct...The time in bold are different...

The code differences between the two executions are only the separation of the function in entrada.c, I havent touched anything more...

Hope someone can help me
Thanks for all in advance
Manuel.

Comment: Are these calculations of some sort or timings?

Comment: Could there be any macros, etc. in the original file that might affect the code you separated out?  Does it reference any global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link line:

> `gcc -o run2sec crowd_2cond.o -lmatheval entrada.o`

is *not* equivalent to the original one. To make it exactly equivalent, try this:

```
gcc -o run2sec crowd_2cond.o entrada.o -lmatheval
```

The order of objects and libraries on the link line [does matter](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

I am not sure that will solve your problem, but that's an immediate difference that I can see.

If the problem remains, it could be that you are using some uninitialized value in your calculations, and the value you get from the original compilation *by chance* produces correct answer. Run your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to make sure no uninitialized values are used.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest of the initialization makes me discovering the error.

The problem was as you said a bad initialization.

```
#ifndef ENTRADA_H
#define ENTRADA_H

#include <stdlib.h> ---This was not in the entrada.h file---
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "tipos.h"

ParametrosEjecucion leerParametrosEntrada(int nparam, char *argv[], int num_lineas);

#endif
```

In the "leerParametrosEntrada", I am using atof to convert from string to float, It seems that this function behaves bad if you do not include the stdlib.h file.

After including it all worked as normal...

Thanks **Employed Russian**